# composition of convex function with harmonic function.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Consider $u:\Omega \to \mathbb R$ be harmonic and $f$ be convex function. How do i prove that $f\circ u$ is subharmonic?

It seems straight forward : $\Delta (f\circ u (x)) \ge f(\Delta u(x))=0 $.
Is this all to this problem? Is there a better way?

Also $|u|^p$ is subharmonic for $p\ge1$ , this seems also very obvious because the map $t\to |t|^p$ is convex mapping.

Any comments, improvements or answers are welcome.

Comment: If you already used Jensens's inequality, it's straight forward

Comment: If $f$ is not differentiable, $f\circ u$ maybe be not differentiable. An alternative way is to check that $$f\circ u(z)\leq \frac 1{2\pi r}\int_0^{2\pi}f\circ u(z+re^{it})dt,$$ using Jensen's inequality and one of your previous threads.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo : But will it not still be a problem when i move derivative inside ? I am a bit confused here but eager to know .

Comment: Subharmonic functions do not need to be differentiable. The usual definition just requires its graph to lie below any harmonic function which is larger on the boundary.

Comment: @WillieWong I should have guessed it was this definition which was used.

Comment: @WillieWong : WillieWong, that means its not very obvious as i have thought . How do i solve this problem ?

Comment: BTW, in the case where $f$ is $C^2$, the correct statement should be $\triangle f\circ u = (f'\circ u)\cdot \triangle u + (f''\circ u)|\nabla u|^2 \geq 0$ using that $f''$ is non-negative and $\triangle u = 0$.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo : Davide, Actually i am not given with a particular definition. The question just says "subharmonic". If its defined like u have assumed how would it change ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basically you do what Davide Giraudo [suggested](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/172820/composition-of-convex-function-with-harmonic-function#comment397081_172820). We use the [definition as given on the EOM](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Subharmonic_function)

> An upper semicontinuous function $v:\Omega \to\mathbb{R}\cup \{-\infty\}$ is called *subharmonic* if for every $x_0 \in \Omega$ and for every $r > 0$ such that $\overline{B_r(x_0)} \subset \Omega$, that 
>   $$ v(x_0) \leq \frac{1}{|\partial B_r(x_0)|} \int_{\partial B_r(x_0)} v(y) \mathrm{d}y $$

Now, using that $f$ is convex, Jensen's inequality takes the following form:

$$ f\left( \frac{1}{|\partial B_r(x_0)|} \int_{\partial B_r(x_0)} v(y)\mathrm{d}y \right) \leq \frac{1}{|\partial B_r(x_0)|}\int_{\partial B_r(x_0)} f\circ v(y) \mathrm{d}y $$

If $u$ is harmonic, we have that

$$ \frac{1}{|\partial B_r(x_0)|} \int_{\partial B_r(x_0)} u(y)\mathrm{d}y = u(x_0) $$

so combining the two facts you have that

$$ f\circ u(x_0) \leq \frac{1}{|\partial B_r(x_0)|}\int_{\partial B_r(x_0)} f\circ u(y) \mathrm{d}y $$

which is precisely the definition for $f\circ u$ to be subharmonic.